# Add data to List of object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am relatively new to .net. I have a situation where I have a class

```
public class Product
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string ean { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string long_description { get; set; }
    public string img_url { get; set; }
    public Size size { get; set; }
    public Style style { get; set; }
    public Brand brand { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public List<Attributes> attributes { get; set; }
}
public class Attributes
{
    public List<Attribute> attribute { get; set; }
}
public class Attribute
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

now my question is I want to add values to List.But facing some problem in adding values to attribute.
I have tried the following,

```
 List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

                    products = (from inventory in inventoryDetails.AsEnumerable()
                                select new Product
                                {
                                    ean = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.ean) ? inventory.ean : null,
                                    sku = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.sku) ? inventory.sku : null,

                                }).ToList();
```

How to add attribute values? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Not getting your actual problem. Please elaborate more.

Comment: In the above snippet, I can easily fill values for ean and sku . But as attributes is also a list I am not able to to so.

Comment: Did you try `attributes = inventory.attributes` in `select new Product` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to write this

**without lambda expression**

```
List<Product> products = (from inventory in inventoryDetails.AsEnumerable()
                        select new Product
                        {
                            ean = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.ean) ? inventory.ean : null,
                            sku = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.sku) ? inventory.sku : null,
                            attributes = inventory.attributes.Select(x => new Attributes
                            {
                                //Set properties

                            }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

**With Lambda Expression**

```
 List<Product> products = inventoryDetails.Select(inventory => new Product
        {
            ean = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.ean) ? inventory.ean : null,
            sku = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.sku) ? inventory.sku : null,
            attributes = inventory.attributes
            // if you want to set properties uncomment below lines and comment above line
            //attributes = inventory.attributes.Select(y => new Attributes
            //{
                ////Set properties

            //}).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share about `inventoryDetails` but you could apply `select` for also `attributes`;

```
products = (from inventory in inventoryDetails.AsEnumerable()
    select new Product
    {
        ean = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.ean) ? inventory.ean : null,
        sku = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inventory.sku) ? inventory.sku : null,
        attributes = inventory.attributes.Select(x => new Attributes
        {
            //Set properties
        })
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

When a model class cantains a List or collection fields we must intiate them at class constructor like this

```
public class Product
{
  public Product()  
  {
   this.attributes = new List<Attributes>();
  }
  public string sku { get; set; }
  public string ean { get; set; }
  public string price { get; set; }
  public string description { get; set; }
  public string long_description { get; set; }
  public string img_url { get; set; }
  public Size size { get; set; }
  public Style style { get; set; }
  public Brand brand { get; set; }
  public Color color { get; set; }
  public Category category { get; set; }
  public List<Attributes> attributes { get; set; }
}
```

If any case **Attribues** model is mapped to database then use Icollection instead of List

```
public Product()  
{
  this.attributes = new ICollection<Attributes>();
}
```